# PySide how to toggle visibility of QTextBrowser

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I want to show/hide QTextBrowser widget by pressing a single button. Is there any mean to toggle it? Now I have two buttons; one for displaying the textbrowser and another for hiding it. Buttons are also hided depending on the visibility of the textbrowser. This implementation works as expected, but I think there should/must be a more sophisticated way to implement it. Any suggestions?

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Program, self).__init__(parent)
    ...code... 
    self.connect(self.showDetailsButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.showTextBrowser)      
    self.textBrowser.hide() #hide the textbrowser by default
    self.resize(461, 200)
    self.connect(self.hideDetailsButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.hideTextBrowser)
    self.hideDetailsButton.hide() #hide the hideDetailsButton by default
...code...

def showTextBrowser(self): 
    self.textBrowser.show()
    self.hideDetailsButton.show()
    self.showDetailsButton.hide()
    self.resize(461, 444)

def hideTextBrowser(self): 
    self.textBrowser.hide()
    self.showDetailsButton.show()
    self.hideDetailsButton.hide()
    self.resize(461, 200)
...code...
```

Dialog is resized whenever the QTextBrowser widget is shown or hided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one button, and one handler. Change the text of the button when it's clicked, and use the current visibility of the browser to toggle between the two states.

Here's a working demo:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Program(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Program, self).__init__()
        self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Hide', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.toggleTextBrowser)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def toggleTextBrowser(self):
        if self.textBrowser.isHidden():
            self.button.setText('Hide')
            self.textBrowser.show()
            self.resize(461, 444)
        else:
            self.button.setText('Show')
            self.textBrowser.hide()
            self.resize(461, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Program()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 461, 444)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This works like a charm - I wasn't aware of .isHidden() -method. Although I am still wondering that obviously there is not a kind of generic .toggle() method for all widgets. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just save the current state and use it to toggle the visibility:

```
def toggleVisibleTextBrowser(self): 
    isVisible= !isVisible # declared somewhere else
    self.textBrowser.setVisible(isVisible) 

    if isVisible:
        self.resize(461, 444)
    else
        self.resize(461, 200)
    ...
```